# What schema stores Omni-Channel data? Data is queriable in website report, not through API

Tags: soql, omnichannel

We have Omni-Channel implemented for all user/agents, I am able to run reports (on the website) against users "Show: All user presences, Current State equals True, etc etc" (results are expected, name, service presence, is current state, capacity info, duration, etc" and that works great.

However I cannot find where this is stored in the database schemas for access from SOQL. Additionally When I dump all the schema objects (standard + custom) there are no columns that grep presence or capacity

Can anyone share with me where that data is located and direct me to where the I would find that for myself documentation wise? I see where the Omni API is which are functions, but not the backing storage for these.

Thank you!

Comment: How about this? https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.omni_channel_dev.meta/omni_channel_dev/

Answer (score 4):

Is this the query you're looking for?

```
SELECT Id, User.Name, ServicePresenceStatus.MasterLabel, StatusDuration, ConfiguredCapacity 
FROM UserServicePresence 
WHERE IsCurrentState = true
```

I used the documentation that @javanoob referenced above and the developer console.

Comment: Fascinating, this UserServicePresense schema doesn't appear in my Schema list (label name or api level name).

Worked great, thank you both.